# How can I display the second half of content in div using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` and i can display the first half of content using `css`. 
But now i have to display the second half of the content.

**Let the content is**

```
"This is a sample div with some content.And this is for test purpose only."
```

**first half may** :   `"This is a sample div with some content."`

**second half may** :  `"And this is for test purpose only."`

**And my code is**

```
<div id="main">
<div id="section1">This is a sample div with some content.And this is for test purpose only.</div>
</div>
#main
{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;

}
#section1
{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background:pink;
    color:blue;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bwyd9/

My `required result` is the div with the content : `"And this is for test purpose only."`

**Note**: the first and second half of content may vary. I provide this only for reference example.

Comment: whats wrong with     height:100%; ?

Comment: @HankLapidez, then it display the full content. I want only the last part of content.

Comment: Why down votes?? Is this question not use full? let me know what is wrong, then i can modify it.

Comment: seriously nice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS `position` property to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="main">
   <div id="section1">This is a sample div with some content.And this is for test purpose only.</div>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <div id="section2"><div>This is a sample div with some content.And this is for test purpose only.</div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main
{
width:200px;
height:100px;
}
#section1
{
width:50%;
height:50%;
background:pink;
color:blue;
overflow: hidden;    
}
#section2
{
width:50%;
height:50%;
background:blue;
color:white;
overflow: hidden;  
position:relative;
}
#section2 div{position:absoltue; margin-top:-50%;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bwyd9/7/)

Comment: no no he is trying to explain this case with your div.you can delete first the section

Comment: what is the problem @next2u?

Comment: I can't believe this is the correct answer, what a terribly worded question.

Answer (score 0):

***Other alternative***

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="section1">
        <div class="p1">This is a sample div with some content.</div>
<div class="p2">
    And this is for test purpose only.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main
{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;

}
#section1 .p1
{    
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:pink;
    color:blue;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
#section1 .p2
{  
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:pink;
    color:blue;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwyd9/8/)

Answer (score -1):

## JavaScript

```
var divVar = document.getElementById("section1");
var str1 = divVar.innerHTML;
var str1 = str1.replace(/^(.*?)[.?!]\s/,"");
divVar.innerHTML = str1;
```

[**Fidde**](http://jsfiddle.net/bwyd9/10/)

This uses RegEx to strip out the first sentence.

Comment: If the content changes, what happened ? Your solution give only the second sentence of the content.Let the content have 10 sentence. Am i correct??

Comment: I understood your question to say "I have xy and want x". My answer is "this is x". I obviously did not understand the question.